# Create process tree in particular order using fork()

Tags: c, process, fork

I attempted to create a process tree in C like in the picture here:

[image]

Please note that the process tree must be created so that it follows the alphabetical order.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
    if(b = fork() == 0)
    {
        if(e = fork() == 0){}
        else
        {
            if(f = fork() == 0)
            {
               sleep(1);
               if(h = fork() == 0){}
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(c = fork() == 0)
        {
            sleep(0.5);
            if(g = fork() == 0){}
        }
        else
        {
            if(d = fork() == 0){}
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used sleep to delay the processes so they can be created in the right order. But I think this isn't the correct way to do it, can anyone please show me the correct and more reliable way?

Comment: My first note is, `if(e = fork() == 0)` is NOT the same as `if((e = fork()) == 0)`. So if the actual code you've been running has variations between those two, they should all actually be the latter (the first, `if(e = fork() == 0)`, will determine whether `fork() == 0` is `true` or `false` and then assign `e` to be that boolean value (if no error occurs, the `true` is likely being casted to be a `1` and `false` to `0`)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that using sleeps is not the right way to do this. You will need to use some form of interprocess communication (IPC).

I would suggest that the simplest way is to use a pipe between parent-child. It will need to be multi-level to support the relationship between B, C, and E.

Something like:

- Each process prints its letter immediately when it starts
- Each process (except A) then sends 'ok' to its parent
- Each process (except A) then it waits for a 'go' message from its parent.
- When it receives the 'go' message, it proceeds to create each of its children in order, waiting to receive 'ok' from each before creating the next.
- When it has received 'ok' from its final child, it then sends 'ok' to its parent, unless it is A (has no parent), in which case it sends 'go' to each of its children in turn, waiting to receive 'ok' before moving on to the next child.
- After creating its children, when a process receives 'go' from its parent, it sends 'go' to each of its children in turn, waiting to receive 'ok' back from each before moving on to the next.

This should be most of a solution, but not complete. You'll need some sort of finishing logic. I would suggest something like

- When a process that has no children receives 'go' from its parent, it sends 'done' back to the parent.
- When a process receives 'done' from *all* of its children, it sends 'done' to its parent.
- When process A receives 'done from all of its children, the game is finished and everyone can pack up and go home.

---

You will need a better structure than a nested bunch of if/else blocks. I suggest making some sort of simple table in a static variable at the top of the file to map which children each node has, and setting a variable to the name of the process before forking it.

Functions will very much be your friend in this exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you show me specifically how can child process wait for message from its parent?

Comment: The `pipe()` call creates two file descriptors, one for reading, one for writing. So you can just use `read()` on the read-side file-descriptor to wait for something to appear in the pipe. I recommend doing a couple of toy programs with fork & pipe - there are loads of articles on the web about how to use these two concepts to talk between parent and child processes.